# Why does encoding JSON struct members not invoking custom MarshalJSON?

Tags: json, go

In Golang, I have a struct whose member is a custom int type with constant values.  Basically, the custom type is a logical enum.

```
type Flavor int

const (
    Vanilla Flavor = iota
    Chocolate
    Strawberry
)

func (f *Flavor) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(strconv.Quote(f.String())), nil
}
```

The custom type has defined MarshalJSON and UnmarshalJSON functions so when I serialize the custom type to JSON, I expect to get the **string** of the value in the serialized output, not the int value.

My issue is that if I have a pointer to a containing type, then the containing type marshals using the custom function but if try to marshal with just a struct value, the custom MarshalJSON is not invoked by the JSON package

```
type Dessert struct {
    Flavor Flavor `json:"flavor"`
    Count  int
}
....
    d := Dessert{Strawberry, 13}

    b, err = json.Marshal(d) // !! does not invoke members Marshal !!
    b, err = json.Marshal(&d) // works as expected
....
```

produces

```
{"flavor":2,"Count":13}
{"flavor":"Strawberry","Count":13}
```

I expected the second output in both case.
Why does passing a struct value not invoke MarshalJSON on the member but it does encode otherwise correct JSON?

see  https://play.golang.org/p/mOl1GHhgynf
for full working code

Comment: Where is your custom MarshalJSON method?

Comment: It is 
   func (f *Flavor) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
see the link in the code sample

Comment: This guy seems to have encountered the same issue. 
https://github.com/golang/go/issues/7536
But  when adding a custom MarshalJSON I can only have either a pointer receiver or a value receiver but not both.

Comment: Please put all relevant code directly in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your code `Flavor` does **not** have a method MarshalJSON as you defined the method for `*Flavor` only.

If you want `type Flavor` to have the MarshalJSON method you must define it on `Flavor` not `*Flavor`.

Comment: I am still wondering, why `json.Marshal(&d)` invokes the custom marshaller, while `json.Marshal(d)`  does not. Do you know why?

Comment: @Leon Because `&d` is of type `*Flavor`. Please read https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets and the linked details.

Comment: I thought the same at first, but printing the type of `(&d).Flavor` and  `d.Flavor` (either with `reflect` or `%T` with `Printf`) both yield `main.Flavor`, not `*main.Flavor`, which makes sense. Also, both `reflect.Type`s return `false` for `Implements(reflect.TypeOf(new(json.Marshaler)).Elem())` (As expected, `true` is returned for the `reflect.PtrTo` type). That is why it surprises me, that the second approach works.

Comment: and the language prevents me from just providing a handler for value and pointer.  This **wont** compile.. I have to pick

    func (f *Flavor) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
     return []byte(strconv.Quote(f.String())), nil
    }

    func (f Flavor) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
     return []byte(strconv.Quote(f.String())), nil
    }

So that means I have to aware when the member members implementation bleeds up to the containing struct level.

Comment: @Leon Ooops, sorry. &d is of type *Desert, so forget the last comment. The reason probably is: Go lets you call pointer-receiver-methods on value-receivers if the value is addressable. If you call json.Marshal(d) you pass a copy of d to json.Marshal and this copy contains a copy of the Flavour. Such copies tend to be not addressable.

Comment: @Leon If you call json.Marshal(&d) then *d.Flavor is addressable and thus you can invoke the ponter-receivermethod on it. Why not define the MarshalJSON _only_ on Flavor like here: https://play.golang.org/p/qJaes9Mfktt

Comment: @Volker Ah okay, that makes sense.

Comment: @Volker Also, I am not the asker, but this behavior surprised me and I mainly wanted to understand why it works the way it does.

Answer (score -1):

oh huh.  I think you had it Volker and Leon. I had assumed that I needed a pointer receiver for MarshalJSON since UnmarshalJSON definitely needs a pointer receiver.  But

```
func (f Flavor) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
...
func (f *Flavor) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
...
```

and mixing the receivers causes the expected output for both json.Marshal(d) **and** json.Marshal(&d)